# Calculating list of existing polygons with distances from newly created QGIS/PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon, distance, array

I have two polygon tables (SRID=4326) in postgres: `t_areas` and `t_sites`. Once I insert through QGIS 3,8 a new area in `t_areas` I'd like PostGIS (by a trigger) to list all sites within a certain km range from new area and insert this list to a `memo` field of the `t_area` table, for ex.: `sitename01 -> 0,3 km, sitename02 -> 0,12 km`... etc. The distance to be calculated between borders, not centroids.

I've managed to compose a query on existing data like:

```
 select array_to_string (array ( SELECT t_sites.shortname || ' -> ' ||
 round(st_distance(geography (t_areas.geom), geography
 (t_sites.geom)))/1000 || ' km' AS distance FROM t_areas, t_sites WHERE
 t_areas.id_area=133 and round(st_distance(geography (t_sites.geom),
 geography (t_areas.geom)))/1000 < 5 ORDER BY distance ASC), ', ')
```

and even got result like this:

```
 Ванино Поле -> 0.661 km, Голубково 1 -> 3.636 km, Голубково 2 -> 4.03
 km, Голубково 3 -> 3.661 km, Задубье 2 -> 0.005 km, Заорешье 1 ->
 4.582 km, Заорешье 2 -> 4.631 km, Калгановка -> 4.385 km, Кут 2 -> 1.526 km, Наволок 1 -> 3.359 km, Петровская Горка 1 - and so on...
```

but I can't realize how to configure a function and a trigger to force PostGIS then automatically update the `t_areas.memo` field since a new area serial `id_area` hasn't been generated yet and so I can't point the function to that id (unlike in the query above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new (or modified) row is available in the trigger using the `NEW` record. You can directly use its geometry or any other attributes to query the 2nd table. The output of the query is then saved in the `NEW` record, and when done the entire record is commited.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tg_f() RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN

        SELECT array_to_string(
            array ( 
                SELECT t_sites.shortname || 
                    ' -> ' ||  
                    round(st_distance(NEW.geom::geography, t_sites.geom::geography))/1000 || ' km' AS distance 
                FROM t_sites 
                WHERE round(
                    st_distance(t_sites.geom::geography, NEW.geom::geography))/1000 < 5 
                ORDER BY distance ASC), ', ')
        INTO new.memo;


        RETURN NEW; -- return the updated row
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tg BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON  public.t_areas FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE  public.tg_f();
```

Comment: This perfectly works!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Done! Tested this solution on a few areas, including 1000 km long and 200 m wide pipeline area to calc archaeological sites within 5, 1 and 0,5 km distance and this works, though saving the updated area record takes 5-6 seconds in qgis. The less area is - the less time takes saving. Similar and a bit modified solution should help to calc also distance and azimuth from a site to settled places around - this is what I'll try next. Thank you again!

Comment: This needs `ST_DWithin`.